# Speech Client DLL for .NetCore

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, speech

I am trying to use the Cognitive Services speech client dll on a windows core app for the IOT build of windows 10. I unfortunately can't use the DLL because it is a .net framework DLL. Is there a .NetCore DLL for Cognitive Services Speech Recognition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

.net Core is supported in the Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK.